# Select tag not including options after the first time

Tags: php, html

Relatively new to php, I want to fetch a column named make for which i am using a loop and mysqli_fetch_row to fetch each row from the column and then i am inserting the data into a select tag. The problem I am facing is that it inserts the data into the options tag the first time, and after that it just echos it out of the list.
Here is the code for it,

```
$SQLstring = "select make from inventory";
$queryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
Or die ("<p>Unable to query the $TableName table.</p>"."<p>Error code ". mysqli_errno($DBConnect). ": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect)). "</p>";
//$row= mysqli_fetch_all($queryResult);
$i=0;
echo"<label for='make'>Please select a make:</label>
<select>
    <option name='make' value='All'>All</option>";
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult)){
    echo"<option value='$row[$i]'>$row[$i]</option>
</select>";
    }
```

What to d0 here?

Comment: You are outputting the closing `</select>` tag _inside_ your loop, so one after each option. You need to do it _once, after_ the loop - same as with the opening tag.

Comment: You're ending your 'select' inside the braces.

Comment: Using the `@mysqli_query` and then `Or die` is redundant, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select>
<option name='make' value='All'>All</option>";
while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult)){
  echo "<option value='$row[$i]'>$row[$i]</option>";
}
</select>
```

Since you are "relatively new to php", here is a good read about **why you shouldn't mix php and html code** or in other words, why you should separate application logic from presentation http://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select>
while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult)){
   echo '<option value="'.$row[$i].'">'.$row[$i].'</option>';
}
</select>
```

Put only `option` tag inside the loop.

Comment: You need to echo <select> or be outside php.

Answer (score 0):

Put the select outside the while loop

```
    $SQLstring = "select make from inventory";
    $queryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
    Or die ("<p>Unable to query the $TableName table.</p>"."<p>Error code ". mysqli_errno($DBConnect). ": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect)). "</p>";
    //$row= mysqli_fetch_all($queryResult);
    $i=0;
    echo"<label for='make'>Please select a make:</label>
    <select>
        <option name='make' value='All'>All</option>";
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult)){
        echo"<option value='$row[$i]'>$row[$i]</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, the probable problem is the placement of your `</select>`.

Try this:

```
echo "<label for='make'>Please select a make:</label><select>";
echo "<option name='make' value='All'>All</option>";
while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult))
    echo "<option value='$row[$i]'>$row[$i]</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Like this, it will only output 'select' once after the options.

As an additional hint, I suggest looking into debugging tools like 'Firebug', which will help you a long way finding problems like these by letting you examine the HTML behind the page you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

simply add name attribute to select tag and remove from option tag.

```
$SQLstring = "select make from inventory";
$queryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
Or die ("<p>Unable to query the $TableName table.</p>"."<p>Error code ". mysqli_errno($DBConnect). ": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect)). "</p>";
$i=0;
echo"<label for='make'>Please select a make:</label>
<select name='make'>
<option value='All'>All</option>";
while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult)){
echo"<option value='$row[$i]'>$row[$i]</option>
</select>";
}
```